# Is every finite subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have a problem asking me to prove that every finite subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed. However, consider a punctured disk $D:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\lVert x\rVert\le 1\}\backslash\vec{0}$. Then we can show that $D$ is not open by considering an open ball on its boundary. But can't we also show that $D$ is not closed by considering the sequence $\{(1/n, 1/n, ..., 1/n|)\}$, which converges to $\vec{0}$, thus proving that $\vec{0}$ is a limit point of $D$? Then $D$ would neither be open nor closed ("clopen"). Isn't it true that clopen sets exist in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

UPD: Oh, I see, I got it. A finite subset is a subset containing finitely many points, not a bounded one...

Comment: Yes, "finite" and "bounded" are quite different things :-)

Comment: You seem to have got it. Just one small note: there is no common word for a set that is neither open nor closed. The word "clopen" refers to a set that is *both* open and closed. In $\mathbb R^n$ these are only $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that every finite subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed. (If a sequence in a finite set converges, then the limit must be one of the points, because you can choose $\epsilon$ to be smaller than half the distance between any two points.) This holds for any metric space.

But that fact seems unrelated to $D$. It is true that $D$ is not closed and not open. (But *clopen* is a different thing: a set is clopen iff it is both closed and open, so it is not clopen if either it is not closed or not open. The only two clopen subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are $\varnothing$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$, because $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected.)

Answer (score 3):

If you are considering $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the topology induced by the Euclidean metric then all singletons are closed i.e any finite set is a finite union of closed sets (singletons). Also, there is nothing special about $\mathbb{R}^n$ for this problem. Every metric space has this property.